# How to remove HTML tags inside of brackets[]?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, shortcode

I have a string like this:

```
[<span style="font-size: 12.1599998474121px; line-height: 15.8079996109009px;">heading </span>heading="h1"]Its a <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">subject</span>.[/<span style="font-size: 12.1599998474121px; line-height: 15.8079996109009px;">heading</span>]
```

I want to remove HTML tags which are inside of brackets using PHP preg_replace etc. Final string should be like this:

```
[heading heading="h1"]Its a <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">subject</span>.[/heading]
```

I searched a lot for finding the solution but no success.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes, I researched a lot and tried many codes but they didn't work for my case.

Comment: In your first bracket you want to delete `headingÂ` because it is between tags, but then at the end you want to keep `heading` which is also between tags, where is the logic?

Comment: No, I don't want to remove first heading. As you can see it's included in final shortcode. Actually I want to remove everything that is inside of <> characters not the content of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just use `strip_tags()` in every brackets of your string and return it.

```
echo $str = preg_replace_callback("/\[(.*?)\]/", function($m){
    return strip_tags($m[0]);
}, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [**callback**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with the following regular expression and utilize [`strip_tags()`](https://php.net/strip_tags) ...

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~\[[^]]*]~', 
     function($m) {
        return strip_tags($m[0]);
     }, $str);
```

[**eval.in**](https://eval.in/343587)

Answer (score 0):

Depends really how much you want to remove.

Example:

```
Pattern: '<.*?>'
Result: [heading heading="h1"]Its a subject.[/heading]
```

But judging from your answer you want to keep the html tags that are inside your heading. I don't understand, based on which rule exactly ? Why is this an exception ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this before but as you said it removes HTML tag that is inside of open short-code and close short-code. I want to remove just HTML tags that are included inside of [] characters. not outside of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single regex to get what you want:

```
$re = "#][^\[\]]*(*SKIP)(*F)|<\/?[a-z].*?>#si"; 
$str = "[<span style=\"font-size: 12.1599998474121px; line-height: 15.8079996109009px;\">heading </span>heading=\"h1\"]Its a <span style=\"text-decoration: line-through;\">subject</span>.[/<span style=\"font-size: 12.1599998474121px; line-height: 15.8079996109009px;\">heading</span>]"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str);
echo $result;
```

Ouput of the [sample code](http://ideone.com/ZUroHn):

```
[heading heading="h1"]Its a <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">subject</span>.[/heading]
```

Comment: Why minus for this reply?! It seems It works correctly!

Comment: The reason could be in the regex for an HTML tag. I edited it, so that only tag-like entities could fit the regex. Anyway, I think Rizier's code is safer to use in general.